# Bash: checking uniqueness of filenames, and renaming or removing files

Tags: bash, files, shell-scripting

I'm working in CentOS with bash and I have files in a directory as follows:

```
16948.png 
16948_thumb.png
16948-1_thumb.png  
16949.png  
16948_thumb.png
16949-1_thumb.png 
16950-1.png  
16950-1_thumb.png
16950-2.png  
16950-2_thumb.png
```

I would like to do the following:

- For each **unique number N** that exists in the list of files:

  - check that there is a file N-1.png:
  - if not, create it by copying N.png to N-1.png (there will always be an N.png)
  - delete the file N.png
  - check that there is a file N-1_thumb.png:
  - if not, create it by copying N_thumb.png to N-1_thumb.png (there will always be an N_thumb.png)
  - delete the file N_thumb.png.

However, my shell scripting isn't good enough to come close to this. This is as far as I've got - can anyone help?

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a unique_numbers
for filename in ./images
do
  // split filename at - or _ to get N, and then check 
  // whether N is already in list of unique numbers
  // if it is, skip
  continue
  // if it isn't, append to unique_numbers
  unique_numbers+=(N)
  // then check whether there is a file N-1.png.. etc
done;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, this should do it. The first loop handles all files named `Number.png` and the second one handles all files named `Number_thumb.png`.

```
#!/bin/sh

for number in `ls -1 images/*.png | grep -v thumb | grep -v "-" | cut -f2 -d / | cut -f1 -d .`
do
  if [ ! -e "./images/$number-1.png" ] ; then
        cp images/"$number.png" images/"$number-1.png"
  fi
  rm ./images/"$number.png"
done;

for number in `ls -1 images/*.png | grep thumb | grep -v "-" | cut -f2 -d / | cut -f1 -d . | cut -f1 -d _`
do
  echo $number
  if [ ! -e "./images/$number-1_thumb.png" ] ; then
        cp images/"$number"_thumb.png images/"$number-1_thumb.png"
  fi
  rm ./images/"$number"_thumb.png
done;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly out of the box, lots of useful techniques in there. Thank you!